# How to list files with special (norwegian) characters

Tags: php, file, character-encoding

I'm doing a simple (I thought) directory listing of files, like so:

```
$files = scandir(DOCROOT.'files');

foreach($files as $file)
{
    echo '  <li>'.$file.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Problem is the files contains norwegian characters (æ,ø,å) and they for some reason come out as question marks. Why is this?

I can apparently fix(?) it by doing this before I echo it out:

```
$file = mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'pass');
```

But it makes little sense to me why this helps, since pass should mean *no character encoding conversion is performed*, according to the docs... **confused**

---

Here is an example: http://random.geekality.net/files/index.php

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I have a tip: try using `DirectoryIterator` (http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) it's a bit newer piece of code than `scandir`, it might work better.

Comment: @webarto Yes, but I've had the same issue on a web host running *nix.

Comment: @kdzwinel Tried it now, and didn't help, unfortunately `:/`

Comment: Have you tried detecting the current encoding?

Comment: there seems to be a relevant [entry in the php bug tracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=30195). specifically lokk at the entry timestamped `[2010-08-29 18:13 UTC]`.

Comment: @collapsar, Interesting. But I'm not doing any actual converting though. I think... Which is why I don't get why this is working.

Comment: Added another example on a different server now. The mb_internal_encoding should be the same, but the result comes out "opposite". Not getting what's going on here...

Answer (score 1):

It appears the encoding of the file names is in ISO Latin 1, but the page is interpreted by default using UTF-8. The characters do not come out as "question marks", but as Unicode replacement characters (�). That means the browser, which tries to interpret the byte stream as UTF-8, has encountered a byte invalid in UTF-8 and inserts the character at that point instead. Switch your browser to ISO Latin 1 and see the difference (View > Encoding > ...).

So what you need to do is to convert the strings from ISO Latin 1 to UTF-8, if you designate your page to be UTF-8 encoded. Use `mb_convert_encoding($file, 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1')` to do so.

Why it works if you specify the `$from` encoding as `pass` I can only guess. What you're telling `mb_convert_encoding` with that is to convert from `pass` to UTF-8. I guess that makes `mb_convert_encoding` take the `mb_internal_encoding` value as the `$from` encoding, which happens to be ISO Latin 1. I suppose it's equivalent to `'auto'` when used as the `$from` parameter.

Comment: Updated the test page to try auto and iso-8859-1 as `from`. iso-8859-1 does indeed work, but for auto the letters seem to just disappear? Also tried putting it on a different server, and there the results are kind of the opposite :s -> http://random.geekality.net/files/

Comment: One thing is for sure: you have to *know* what encoding you're dealing with and convert appropriately. Letting a piece of software attempt auto-conversion on arbitrary encodings is bound to give you rather random results. Why it behaves this particular kind of random is anyone's guess.

Comment: But if I deploy to a random server, how can I know what encoding I should be using? I mean, converting from mb_internal_encoding failed in one of my examples.

Comment: I simply suspect that different operating systems will give you the file names in different encodings. Sorry, don't really have a clear answer for that part of the question.